# Java app deployment and updating in a Remove Desktop Services environment

Tags: java, windows, deployment, remote-desktop

I have a Java app which needs to be used in a [Remote Desktop Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee236407) environment.

As the javaw.exe process holds a file handle of the JAR file, I can not replace the JAR as long as other users are working with it.

I can also not see the current users as there might be many other javaw.exe processes for other JAR files running on the same server. And in a server farm I would have to check every single server for open instances.

Is there a best practice to deploy and update Java apps in this environment?

Some ideas:

- use a launcher app which has a configuration file which specifies the location of the JAR file
- modify the entry in the start menu to point to the new JAR file location
- copy the jar to a user-specific work folder on logon
- use JWS

Option 3 and 4 however would mean that Log4J output needs to be directed to a location in a folder which can be accessed by operations / developers

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes, thanks for noticing! I have updated the question. Yes, they have a (Swing) user interface.

Comment: In the case of Swing, you might deploy the app. using [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) - it has auto-update 'built in'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson if JWS uses a user-spcific install directory this would be interesting